# What has been done with Multi monitor support in Delphi 10 Seattle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I read the new features list in Delphi 10 Seattle, I see these:

1. Improved multi-monitor support in the IDE, with the ability to place most forms and panes on different secondary monitors
2. Enhanced IDE Project Options to easily enable High-DPI Awareness in your applications, plus Windows 8.1/10 multi-monitor support for VCL applications

Isn't the Windows 7 or above has multi monitor (or dual view) support?  What's more has Delphi IDE offer for multi monitor supports?

Answer (score 13):

Item 1 seems clear enough to me. Some forms in the **IDE** can now be placed on different monitors. This is unrelated to the Windows version, and is a change to the IDE.

As for item 2, that concerns DPI awareness for your **applications**. There is a new project option that allows you to control the DPI awareness setting that is used in the IDE generated manifest. Previous versions of the IDE had no such setting and the IDE generated manifest did not include a DPI awareness setting.

Furthermore, the VCL now has per-monitor DPI awareness. That is, the VCL responds to `WM_DPICHANGED` by scaling forms to the new monitor's DPI scaling.

Per-monitor DPI scaling was introduced in Windows 8.1 to account for the vastly different DPI scaling needed for traditional sized monitors, very large so-called 4k monitors, high pixel density monitors and so on.

The new VCL functionality goes some way to addressing the issue but neglects one critical point. When scaling a form, different sized glyphs must be used for toolbar buttons, menus and so on. Nothing has been changed to account for this and you the developer will need to tackle the issue if you don't want your glyphs to look ridiculously tiny under high DPI scaling.

For more details on DPI aware applications:

- [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx).
- [New per-DPI awareness in VCL applications (Embarcadero Community)](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/new-per-dpi-awareness-in-vcl-applications).

Comment: how have you approached the problem of rescaling glyphs. We are facing this exact problem now. We use DevExpress and are trying to find a good solution to this problem.
We currently use ImageLists and so far the best solution is to use different image lists for different DPI scales.
100% DPI scale -> 16 x 16
125% DPI scale -> 20 x 20
150% DPI scale -> 24 x 24
...

Comment: I use one image list and load the icons from resources at the appropriate DPI level. But I've not tackled per-monitor DPI yet. For that I think I'd have one image list for each size, as you say, but certainly I'd be loading at runtime from resources.